# How to make button like this via compound view?

Tags: android, button, view

I want to make a button like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKolB.png) by a compound view!

[image]

I am following [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-compound-views-on-android--cms-22889) tutorial, but I am not able to make a view like this.

Can anybody show me some direction?

Comment: *I am not able to make a view like this*... Please show us some attempts and where you got stuck.

Comment: did you try anything ?

Comment: Check this link :http://stackoverflow.com/a/40947825/1770868

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Facebook add badge numbers on app icon in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17510419/how-does-facebook-add-badge-numbers-on-app-icon-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    <FrameLayout   
    android:layout_width="210dp"
    android:layout_height="210dp"
    //set framelayout clickable
    ><Button
        android:id="@+id/filter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="7dp"
        android:background="#0000FF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="25dp"
        android:paddingTop="25dp"
        android:text="Sort"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/widget_title_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|right"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:paddingTop="-10dp"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:src="@drawable/checkbtn" />

</FrameLayout>
```

play around with this :   `android:paddingTop="-10dp"`

this is what it will look like somewhat : [here is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYQ7t.png)

Comment: play around with this :  ` android:paddingTop="-10dp" `