# How does Marshmallow show Notification Badges?

Tags: android, notifications, android-6.0-marshmallow, badge

I understand Notification Badge in Android is only available after [Android 8.0](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/badges) (correct me if i am wrong)

I have created an app, which works on my Huawei, Android 8.

Now, the thing is, I have another Huawei phone, with Android 6. Somehow, some apps are able to show notification badge.

[image]

How are they doing it? When i install my app here, there is no badge at all... Did i miss out anything?

Comment: For that you need to create custom badge for the application. or another option is create android widget for the custom badge on the launcher icon

Comment: Notification badges are available after Android OS -> 7 (Nogut)

Comment: Btw, this may help -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17510419/how-does-facebook-add-badge-numbers-on-app-icon-in-android

Comment: Thanks all. Really appreciate the info. I think i should omit 'notification' in my search, and should look for 'badge' instead. 'Notification badge' on the search engine will mostly land on the results that are not for android < 8.. >.<

Comment: @Dennis Again great thanks for the link. "ShortcutBadger" is the thing i am looking for :)