# How to show number of unread sms on mesege inbox icon

Tags: java, android

when sms is recieved a pop up is appeared on inbox icon which show number of unread sms,, how can i show that popup which indicate number of unread sms in inbox....
[Is there a way to add a badge to an application icon in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905542/is-there-a-way-to-add-a-badge-to-an-application-icon-in-android)

Comment: Check this link :1.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19086189/adding-notification-badge-on-app-icon-in-android 2.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20136483/how-do-you-interface-with-badgeprovider-on-samsung-phones-to-add-a-count-to-the/20136484#20136484 3.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20216806/how-to-add-a-notification-badge-count-to-application-icon-on-sony-xperia-devices/ Hope it will help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Android does not allow changing of the application icon because it's sealed in the APK once the program is compiled. There is no way to programmatically change it to a 'drawable'.

Read this link: [Is there a way to add a badge to an application icon in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905542/is-there-a-way-to-add-a-badge-to-an-application-icon-in-android?lq=1)

Comment: what you are pointing is when you want to show popup on your specific app icon which you are developing,, In my case i am developing an sms locker when sms is from specific number add this to database of my app else insert it to inbox,, there my problem arises when i save it in inbox i need to show popup on inbox icon..

Comment: looking for comments in your question, sound as it can help u :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to implement this for all devices out there. The problem is, this is no feature of Android by itself, but of the specific launcher, and while there are some launchers that offer this possibility (each slightly differently), there is no solution that would work with all devices.

Also, it is discouraged to use this UI pattern in Android apps, as it is an iOS design pattern.