# show unread notifications dynamically in footer android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-facebook

my requirement is to show unread notification count on footer like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOaK0.jpg

am new to android and i really have no idea how to achieve this, i googled for this but not getting results.

this is my footer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/footer_1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:background="@color/footer_bg"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/footer_background"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/footer_home_icon"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:duplicateParentState="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:src="@drawable/home_menu" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/footer_home"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:duplicateParentState="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/footer_home"
                android:textColor="@drawable/footer_text"
                android:textSize="@dimen/footer_text" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/alert_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/footer_background"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/footer_alert_icon"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:src="@drawable/alert_menu" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/footer_alert"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/footer_alert"
                android:textColor="@drawable/footer_text"
                android:textSize="@dimen/footer_text" />
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

can anyone please tell me how i can do this?

Many thanks in advanced!!

Comment: Can you display Badge count into Tab?

Comment: not able to get you? could you please explain me in detail?

Comment: you talk in about like this structure :[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8476544/ui-help-for-notification-on-icon/20437659#20437659](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8476544/ui-help-for-notification-on-icon/20437659#20437659)

Comment: Are asking about how to create a similar layout as shown in the image screen shot or asking how to implement the code? to show the "count"?

Comment: basically am new to android and i have no idea how to implement this if you show some implementation examples that helps me to pick up the thing that could be great.. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can create a layout like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/footer_1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="56dp"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_widget3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:focusable="true" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/brisbane"
            android:contentDescription="image"
            android:scaleType="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/footer_alert3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/icon3"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Brisbane"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="10dip" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_count"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-10dip"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon3"
            android:background="@drawable/badge_count3"
            android:contentDescription="badge"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_widget2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:focusable="true" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bike"
            android:contentDescription="image"
            android:scaleType="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/footer_alert2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/icon2"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Bike"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="10dip" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_count"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-10dip"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon2"
            android:background="@drawable/badge_count3"
            android:contentDescription="badge"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_widget"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:focusable="true" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bowls"
            android:contentDescription="image"
            android:scaleType="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/footer_alert"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/icon"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Bowls"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="10dip" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_count"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-10dip"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
            android:background="@drawable/badge_count3"
            android:contentDescription="badge"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

badge_count2.xml file

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<solid android:color="@color/red" >
</solid>

<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="#FFFFFF" >
</stroke>

<padding
    android:bottom="2dp"
    android:left="7dp"
    android:right="7dp"
    android:top="3dp" />

<corners android:radius="10dp" >
</corners>
```

add red color into your string.xml file

```
<color name="red">#e50822</color>
```

and now you can visible or invisible this view as per your requirement. Customized by your self. Thnx 
Below snap have a look:
[image]